# Angular 5 - Bindings cannot contain assignments

Tags: angular5

```
<li class="tabRow tabRowLeft" *ngFor="let gene of filteredgene = (seq.genes) | limitTo:filteredgene.length/2+filteredgene.length%2">
    <div class="displayFlex" (click)="showGeneRecord(gene.geneName,'ATTRIBUTE','.addPopup.attributeRisk')">
      <div class="tabCell">
    <div class="cellItem displayFlex">
    <h4 class="flex1">{{gene.geneName}}</h4>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tabCell">
    <div class="cellItem displayFlex">
     <h4 class="flex1">{{gene.geneScore}}</h4>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

I am trying to get the value in filteredgene and then for loop on filteredgene . I am getting error Bindings cannot contain assignments. Any one knows, what should I do resolve and get this thing done.
For limit to I have created a pipe too.

Comment: The base issue is having `filteredgene = (seq.genes)` in the first part of the ngFor, but the exact solution will depend on what filteredgene represents. Is filteredgene a variable in your component, or are you trying to assign seq.genes to it? Do you use filteredgene for anything other than the limitTo?

Comment: I am trying to assign seq.genes to filteredgene.